# youtube player api does not work in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

youtubeplayerview will work in emulator or not ,which version mobile support ,which version API emulator will work

please give full detail of youtubeplayerview and working source code

thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the youtube app in your emulator to make youtubeplayerview work on it.
For sample code see this-[click here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/using-googles-youtube-api-in-your-android-apps/)